# C++ static_cast runtime overhead

Tags: c++, runtime, overhead, static-cast

See the code below.

a) Does, in this case (simple inheritance, no virtual members), the static cast in B::df() have any overhead (whatsoever)? I found some conflicting answers to similar questions, that's why I am asking...

b) I was thinking about making `const M1 * func` private in A and introducing a new private field `const M2 * func` into B to avoid the cast, but it kind of complicates things up and makes use of smart pointers more difficult. Do you see a better way to avoid the cast?

```
class M1 {
public:
    double f() const;
};
```

class M2 : public M1 {
public:
    double df() const;
};

class A {
protected:
    const M1 * func;
public:
    A(const M1 * p);
    ~A();
    double f() const;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B(const M2 * p);
    double df() const;
};

```
double M1::f() const { return 1973.0; }
double M2::df() const { return 0.0; }
```

A::~A() { delete func; }
A::A(const M1 * p) : func(p) {}
double A::f() const { return func->f(); }

B::B(const M2 * p) : A(p) {}
double B::df() const { return static_cast<const M2*>(func)->df(); }

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`static_cast<T>(e)` is equivalent to creating an invented temporary variable v in the following way:

```
T v(e); //where T is an arbitrary type  and e is an arbitrary expression.
```

The runtime cost of a static_cast is exactly the cost of the above statement

Comment: So it does have some overhead in creating that temporary object every time B::df() is called. From this point of view it could be advantageous to store one more member variable in B to avoid the temporary. Right?

Comment: @Petr: You are casting pointers. A copy of a pointer (which may be optimized away by the compiler anyway) is a negligable operation. I wouldn't try to optimize it