# What is the static_cast runtime overhead if adding constness while keeping the same type?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, static-cast

I find it irritating that I can call non-const functions of an object if I have a pointer to this object. I cannot let the pointer be a const pointer because there are also non-const functions I need to call. Therefore, my only option seems to do static_casts to ensure that constness also works across pointers. Here is a minimal example:

```
class MyClassImpl
{
  MyClassImpl(void) : m_i(0) {}

  int increment(void) {
    ++m_i;
    return m_i;
  }

  private:
    int m_i;
};

class MyClass
{
  MyClass(void) : m_pImpl(new MyClassImpl()){}

  ~MyClass(void) {
    delete m_pImpl;
  }

  int doNothing(void) const {
    m_pImpl->increment(); // works although MyClassImpl::increment() is non-const
    // static_cast<const MyClassImpl *>(m_pImpl)->increment(); // this will not compile because of non-constness
  }


  private:
  MyClass(const MyClass & rhs);
  MyClassImpl * m_pImpl;
};
```

However, I wonder if the static_cast has any cost at runtime. Are static_casts completely evaluated at compile time or is there some overhead, assuming that doNothing() is called often.

Edit:
My question is different from [C++ static_cast runtime overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445841/c-static-cast-runtime-overhead) because in my case, the static_cast only adds const. Other users finding this question might be interested in the mentioned question.

Comment: The Overhead depends on the types. If you only add const, then there is no Overhead.

Comment: Why a `static_cast` instead of a `const_cast`?

Comment: @nwp: A static_cast may add constness but not remove it. A const_cast can remove constness. Hence, the static_cast is safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The runtime overhead is essentially a pointer copy, which may be optimised out altogether.

**But** in your case, I'd consider changing `int m_i;` to `mutable std::atomic<int> m_i;` and make `increment` constant in the base class too. It looks like a reference counter and my way allows you to (i) retain `const`-correctness and (ii) be thread safe. I'd also consider changing `int` to `unsigned` to avoid undefined behaviour if `m_i` gets too big.

Comment: Why would the pointer be copied ? In that case, only `const`-qualification changes, so it's most probably a no-op.

Comment: Indeed, the compiler might optimise out a temporary. But it's no **worse** than a pointer copy.