# Do static casts take execution time?

Tags: c++

I know that dynamic_cast does take execution time and even considered slow, but does static_cast take execution time as well? Here's an example code

```
void printv(const void *str) {
    std::cout << *static_cast<const std::string*>(str) << "\n";
}

void prints(const std::string *str) {
    std::cout << *str << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::string str("my string");

    printv(&str);
    prints(&str);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Will `printv()` take longer than `prints()` because it includes a cast inside?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445841/c-static-cast-runtime-overhead- This may be better suitable to considered as a duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`static_cast` MAY take time at run-time. For example, if you convert `int` to `float` then work is required. Usually casting pointers does not require any run-time cost.