# Efficient division operator for 3D vectors

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, division, sfinae, micro-optimization

I have a simple class template for 3D vectors:

```
template <typename T>
struct Vec3
{
    T x, y, z;  // vector components
    ...
}
```

where the template parameter `T` can be `int`, `float` or `double` (for now anyway). I have two requirements when overloading the division operator:

- it must be as efficient as possible.
- it must be available only for floating point types

I came up with this short implementation:

```
template <typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>>>
Vec3 operator/(T a) const
{
    assert(a != 0);
    T inva = static_cast<T>(1.0)/a;
    return Vec3{inva*x, inva*y, inva*z};
}
```

A few questions regarding this piece of code:

- Is there another non-SFINAE way to restrict this member function to floating
  point types? (I am using C++17)
- Are modern compilers smart enough to compute the division first and
  then perform three multiplications? Is it a waste of time
  and expressiveness to do that myself?
- Is it worth using a variable template for the constant `1.0`? Will the compiler be smart enough to do the static_cast at compile time? [C++ static_cast runtime overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445841/c-static-cast-runtime-overhead)

  ```
  template<typename T>
  constexpr T one = T(1.0);
  ```

EDIT: gcc didn't mind, but clang wouldn't compile the code above. This is because my usage of SFINAE is incorrect. A correct implementation would be

```
template <typename U = T,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<U>>>
Vec3 operator/(T a) const
{
    ...
}
```

more details can be found here: [std::enable_if to conditionally compile a member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368/stdenable-if-to-conditionally-compile-a-member-function/25483768)

Comment: "smart enough" yes, but only if you let them by using `-ffast-math`, unless the divisor is known to have a reciprocal that's exactly representable as a `T`.  e.g. yes for compile-time-constant powers of 2, like `2.0` and `0.5`, because binary floating point can represent such fractions.  Introducing an inexact reciprocal is not allowed by ISO C++ / IEEE-754 rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - Is there another non-SFINAE way to restrict this member function to floating point types? (I am using C++17)

- Full or partial specialization of the class (for partial specialization, it would requires changes to make class SFINAE-friendly).
- overloads as free functions (as `std::is_floating_point_v` is true only for few types (`float`, `double`, `long double` (+ cv_variant)))

  ```
  Vec3<float> operator / (const Vec3<float>& vec, float value) {/*..*/}
  Vec3<double> operator / (const Vec3<float>& vec, float value) {/*..*/}
  Vec3<long double> operator / (const Vec3<float>& vec, float value) {/*..*/}
  ```

SFINAE seems the better alternative.

C++20 would introduce `requires` to discard those methods cleanly:

```
Vec3 operator/(T a) const requires(std::is_floating_point_v<T>) {/*..*/}
```

> - Are modern compilers smart enough to compute the division first and then perform three multiplications? Is it a waste of time and expressiveness to do that myself?

With floating point, result might differs, so compiler won't do that (unless it can ensure it would result in same result).

> - Is it worth using a variable template for the constant 1.0? Will the compiler be smart enough to do the static_cast at compile time?

I will trust compiler to replace the code `static_cast<float>(1.0)` by `1.f`.