# Issues with templated methods used with templated function pointer to an inherited method

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++98

I can't seem to figure out what is going on with a particular templated method.

A similar templated method has been in my codebase for a while now and has been used in an identical manner as `Bar::Bar(IFoo&)`, the only difference being that the function being passed in is inherited.

I have an interface `IFoo` which defines the templated function in question.

```
struct IFoo {
    template<class T>
    void doSomething(bool (T::*method)(int), T *instance) {
        std::cout << (instance->*method)(5) << "\n";
    }
};
```

I have a class `Bar` which is a child of another class

```
struct Parent {
    virtual bool setValue(int a) { return true; }
};
struct Bar : Parent { };
```

When I try to use `IFoo::doSomething` the compiler just doesn't see the matching function

```
int main() {
    Bar b;
    IFoo foo;
    foo.doSomething(&Bar::setValue, &b);
}
```

I get the following compiler message
error: no matching function for call to '`IFoo::doSomething(bool (Parent::*)(int), Bar*)`'

What I'm really surprised about is that I don't get a candidate suggestion that for the templated `IFoo::doSomething` function.

C++98 solutions only please.

Comment: Doesn't do call itself instead of the virtual method?

Comment: I'm so sorry you still are forced to use c++98

Comment: `do` is a keyword in C++. You cannot name a method like that

Comment: One do method is private and has different parameters than the public version I'm trying to use.

Comment: I'll edit and rename the method in my example its not called that in my codebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, the type of `Bar::setValue` is actually `bool (Parent::*)(int)`. This interferes with the template parameter deduction for `doSomething` because it has two `T`s that need to be the same. You can help the compiler with the deduction by casting `this`:

```
int main() {
    Bar b;
    IFoo foo;
    foo.doSomething(&Bar::setValue, static_cast<Parent*>(&b));
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/48nWsY)

Thanks to JVApen for pointing out that alternatively you can make `doSomething` more generic by allowing two different types and let `Callback` do the conversion:

```
template<class T, class U>
void doSomething(bool (T::*method)(int), U *instance);
```

Comment: Alternatively, one could use 2 template parameters and let Callback implicitly upcast the Bar to a Parent pointer: https://godbolt.org/z/6adT8x

Comment: @JVApen thanks for the link. I thought the same, but admittedly was too lazy to verify that it works ;)

Comment: I was gonna add `static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<T, U>)`, however, that didn't exist 22 years ago

Comment: Sadly static_cast is computationally expensive and that may be an issue for me.

Comment: @lancegerday "static_cast is computationally expensive"  this must be a misunderstanding. Why do you think so?

Comment: @HTNW yes, caused some confusion here, but once I understood it I agree with the edit

Comment: @lancegerday As you can see on https://godbolt.org/z/oGGebY, there ain't assembly linked to the static_cast (and you don't need it, see right below it)

Comment: @lancegerday see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445841/c-static-cast-runtime-overhead. Don't miss the comment under the accepted answer. `static_cast` from a derived to base pointer is almost free

Comment: There's also the template dark magic "deduction blocker": `template<class T> struct type_identity { /* stolen from C++20 */ typedef T type; }; template<class T> void doSomething(bool (T::*method)(int), typename type_identity<T>::type *instance);`, in which `doSomething(&Bar::setValue, &b)` works because only `&Bar::setValue` contributes to the choice of `T = Parent`. The upcast then becomes implicit.

Comment: Alternatively, you can cast the other argument: `static_cast<bool (Bar::*)(int)>(&Bar::setValue)`